# What would be a smart way to check if an array is in records in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have the following products table:

```
user    product
1       999
2       888
2       777
3       999
3       888
3       777
```

So far, I've been using `where ... in ...` queries.

For example, to get the details of the customers who have the products 999 and 888 I was executing `select * from users u where 999 in (select p.product from products p where p.user=u.id) and 888 in (select p.product from products p where p.user=u.id)`.

This works for small number of product ids but when I need to check more products it takes quite a long time.

Is there a way to speed up the execution process maybe through something like `... where (888, 999) in (select p.product from products p where p.user=u.id)`?

Comment: Go read some of the many Q&A here on query optimization. Pay attention to those which are voted up - they include essential information like table/index structures and execution plans. The really good ones include information about data cardinality. In your case you also need to be specific about where this set of literals is coming from and how large it might be.

Answer (score 1):

Try to write it as a join:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users u 
JOIN products p on p.user = u.id
WHERE p.product IN (888,999)
```

If you only want to have the users that have all products, it gets a little bit more complicated. You can use the GROUP_CONCAT function to map an ordered list of product ids to each user. Now you can easily search with a like expression. But you need to wrap both the productlist and the searchstring with the separators.

```
SELECT * FROM user U JOIN ( SELECT user,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT product) productlist FROM products GROUP BY user ORDER BY GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT product) ASC ) UP ON U.user_id = up.user WHERE concat(',', productlist, ',') like '%,888,999,%'
```